# add float to Json Obj incorrect decimal

Tags: php, json

Using PHP I am trying to add a float number 0.3 to a object then encode it but when I encode the object the float gets changed to a long decimal number.

```
<?php
   $test = 0.3;
   $data = new stdClass();
   $data->test = $test;
   echo json_encode ($data);
?>
```

Comment: Works as expected (with a minor fix): https://3v4l.org/ZQmih (output is `{"test":0.3}`). But this might be an interesting read: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/1941241)

Comment: Sorry made type error on line three of code. Just edited. I get {"test":0.29999999999999999} in result were I was expecting {"test":0.3}. I will have a read of the link you posted

Answer (score 1):

Save your number as a string :

```
   $test = "0.3";
```